# awk - is it possible to define my custom new line character/word?

Tags: awk, sed, grep

AWK reads and procesess input data line by line. My data has it's own defination of line. So is it possible to configure AWK to consider a char or word i define as end of line.
Just like with `-F` option we define the field seperator. Similarly is it possible to define line seperator too.

Note: If this is possible, does the same apply to grep and other similar linux utils.

Comment: [How Input Is Split into Records](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Records)

Comment: `cat myfile | awk 'BEGIN { RS = "@git" } {print  }'` and it worked. Could you please upvote the Q. Its quite valid and looks at depth of AWK. Would be gald to accept your answer if you wish to post one.

Comment: please consider upvoting. It checks up advanced (if not too advanced) stuff of awk. I don't understand why someone would downvote it with out reasoning.

Comment: A related Q on filed sperator. Up votes +310 [How can I use ":" as an AWK field separator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609552/how-can-i-use-as-an-awk-field-separator). And current Q, wihich goes one step futher is getting down voted?? Clearly Unfair. Stop it and instead upvote so it helps others.

Comment: The question is about absolutely basic awk functionality with the answer to it clearly stated in the awk man page, never mind the manual. It also contains none of the 3 things required as a starting point for a good question (i.e. sample input, expected output, and your code attempt to solve your problem). Please see [ask] to learn how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> AWK reads and procesess input data line by line.

More precisely, awk reads and processes *records* - the default *record separator* `RS` just happens to be the newline character.

There is no direct command-line equivalent of the `-F` switch (which is equivalent to modifying the *field separator* internal variable, `FS`) but you can specify an alternate record separator by modifying `RS` directly, which is usually done either in a begin block

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS='@'} ... '
```

or via the command line using the `-v` variable passing option

```
awk -v RS='@' ' ... '
```

See also the following sections of The GNU Awk User's Guide:

- [4.1 How Input Is Split into Records](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Records)
- [7.5.1 Built-in Variables That Control awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#User_002dmodified)

Although specific to the GNU implementation of awk, the guide indicates where the behavior is implementation-specific. In particular, not all implementations support the use of regular expressions for `RS` (in fact, the [POSIX specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/utilities/awk.html) only provides for a single character separator).